# How do I modify and run a chunk of code from my .py file without having to read the whole .xlsx file every time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the data
filepath = "data.xlsx"
data = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col = 0)

print(data)
```

The problem: There are over a million rows in data.xlsx.
Suppose I have some code beneath this that I wish to modify repeatedly and run my python file again, how do I do so without waiting for my computer to read all the 1 million rows of data over and over again?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. As long as the script hasn't exited, the variable `data` should persist in memory. How are you running the script? In an IDE, a jupyter notebook, or through a shell? Are you trying to persist the variable in memory between code runs in production, or are you developing a function that you are just re-running? If the latter, you should be using an IDE or notebook that allows for debugging and repeated execution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to work with a cell-based IDE. [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) is a very popular cell-based IDE that runs within your browser and comes with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) (a popular scientific python distribution).

[image]

In this case, you run the code in each cell independently so you only run the loading code once and can have many other cells with code that works with your `data` variable without having to reload it each time.